# how to put two marker at a distance of 500m in google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How we can put two markers at a distance of 500 meter, lets say latLng for first marker is london (51,0) and second marker is put ad a distance of 500m from this marker. I have tried ever thing but couldnt find and answer for it.. any ideas

Answer (score 0):

A degree of latitude is 60 nautical miles but obviously that goes out of the window for longitude.

Therefore it sounds like you would need to use the Great Circle Distance Equation in reverse.

GDC gives you the distance between to points on the Earth - it's complicated because it's not a straight line as you have to negotiate the curvature of the sphere.

If you could work the GDC in backwards you'd be able to work out the LatLong of a point 500m away from the current one.

(Obviously this only applies as the crowflies. A route following a road would be different. The Google directions service returns distance in metres though IIRC.)

Comment: Maybe you can even simplify the equation a little, because the impact of the curvature will be insignificant for 500m distance.

Comment: @ Mark Holland Thanks mark, I was wondering if I want to place two marker at a distance of 500 meter how it wouldnt fit into window. lets say latLng of london is (50,0) and I want to place a marker at 500 meter away then what I would have to do. If I go a bit further with my question then how would I place a marker randomly at a distance of 500 meter from london(50,0) or anywhere in a radius of 500 meter

Comment: @Mark Holland Thanks mark, I was wondering if I want to place two marker at a distance of 500 meter how it wouldnt fit into window. lets say latLng of london is (50,0) and I want to place a marker at 500 meter away then what I would have to do. If I go a bit further with my question then how would I place a marker randomly at a distance of 500 meter from london(50,0) or anywhere in a radius of 500 meter

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into Google Maps API and it appears that my answer was really wrong. I haven't noticed that latLng doesn't work with length but latitude and longitude (it looks as if i have forgotten that earth is not flat :) ). Using [this](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) nice web site I was able to came up with better solution:

```js
var position = new google.maps.LatLng(51.517289, -0.130463);  
var latlngs = [];
var map;
// distance from position in km
var d = 5;
// Earth radius
var R = 6372;

function initialize()
{
    var mapOptions = { zoom: 12,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
              center: position };    
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
}

function dropMarkers()
{
    var lat1Deg = position.lat();
    var lon1Deg = position.lng();
    var lat1Rad = lat1Deg.toRad();
    var lon1Rad = lon1Deg.toRad();

    latlngs.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        draggable: false,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP}));

    for (var brngDeg = 0; brngDeg < 360; brngDeg+=20)
    {
        brngRad = brngDeg.toRad();
        var lat2Rad = Math.asin( Math.sin(lat1Rad)*Math.cos(d/R) + 
                      Math.cos(lat1Rad)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brngRad) );
        var lon2Rad = lon1Rad + 
                      Math.atan2(Math.sin(brngRad)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(lat1Rad),  
                      Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(lat1Rad)*Math.sin(lat2Rad));

        lat2Deg = lat2Rad.toDeg();
        lon2Deg = lon2Rad.toDeg();
        latlngs.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat2Deg,lon2Deg),
                    map: map,
                    draggable: false,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP}));
    }
}

if (typeof(Number.prototype.toRad) === "undefined")
{
    Number.prototype.toRad = function()
    {
    return this * Math.PI / 180;
    }
}
if (typeof(Number.prototype.toDeg) === "undefined")
{
    Number.prototype.toDeg = function()
    {
    return this * 180 / Math.PI;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am a newbee in java script and dun really know how to change from c# to java script can  you help me in this please and also what do you mean but randomize angle, can you send me the code. I would really appreciate. Thanks