# how to put two marker at a distance of 500m in google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to put two marker at a distance of 500m in google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855690/how-to-put-two-marker-at-a-distance-of-500m-in-google-map)

I was wondering if anyone know how we can put two markers at a distance of 500 meter, lets say I put first marker at london(50,0) and second marker at some location 500 meter away from london(50,0). how would it happen. I have been looking a lot for it but couldnt find any answer. 
Any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
θ is the bearing (in radians, clockwise from north);
d/R is the angular distance (in radians), where d is the distance travelled and R is the earth’s radius
```

src: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

```
var lat2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(d/R) + 
                      Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brng) );
var lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(lat1), 
                             Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2));
```

Alternative:

The way I do it in OpenLayers is reproject my coordinate to epsg:900913 which is meters, do my calculations, and then convert back to the original projection. This can be accomplished with the pro4.j library: http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/

Comment: thank you, I want to create a circular path (start and end location is same) of 45 min in such a way that when I click  a point on map in creates three random point from this point on map in such a way  that distance from A to A is 45 min for example A-b-c-d-A. when b,c,d are three random points on map. Any idea about it

Comment: how to calculate bearing or it could be any thing randon like 45 or 90 or ....

Comment: all the angles should all add up to 360 degrees and just split 500m into 4 parts for the segment lengths.